# MUI v5 / v4 Scrollable Tabs Not Working on RTL Mode

Tags: material-ui

I am experiencing an issue with scrollable tabs on MUI v4 and v5. The tabs work fine on LTR mode, but once I switch them to RTL mode, the scroll stop working.
I tried so much to solve this issue, but nothing worked for me. This issue was tiring me for like a month without any solution.

This issue is the same in v5 and v4 as I saw they didn't fix it at all.

Here is a CodeSandbox example I made with `Next.js` and MUI v5. You can see the issue when you click on the above button and switch to RTL mode. The scroll stops working or it stays on LTR mode. Also, I noticed that it works fine on mobile.

This is the link for my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-borg-7u66f

You can see my work on RTL mode inside `_app.js`.

And in this link, I deployed this example on Vercel: https://mui-v5-rtl-tabs.vercel.app/